# How to create a burn down for an epic in TFS?

Tags: tfs

This question is on how to use either TFS build in reporting or any other means to create a burn up or burn down the chart.

I have an epic, which spawns multiple iterations, and some may not be even assigned to an iteration. Is it possible to create either a burnup or burndown for only that Epic?

Thanks

Comment: There is no Epic work item type in TFS 2012, do you customize it?

Comment: Yes, we have it as Epic->Feature->Workitems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try PivotTable in Excel, and filter the work item type, then you'll get Epic work item type and all iteration paths:

[image]